# Validation problems while creating record through file import using Roo gem and following railscast

Tags: csv, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, railscasts, roo-gem

I am trying to create records through file imports format can be csv excel etc
and I have implemented it following the Railscast396. but as I import file it says 
"**Validation failed: Email can't be blank, Password can't be blank**. Here is my code

```
    class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  has_many :quizzes
  has_many :classrooms

  #to import file
  **def self.attr_names
    [:email, :password, :password_confirmation]
  end**

  def self.import(file)
    spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
    header = spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
      row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
      row.inspect
      student = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new
      student.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*attr_names)
      student.save!
    end
  end

  def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
  case File.extname(file.original_filename)
    when ".csv" then Roo::CSV.new(file.path, file_warning: :ignore)
    when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new(file.path, file_warning: :ignore)
    when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path, file_warning: :ignore)
    else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
  end
end

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

**view is**

```
<%= form_tag addStudents_classrooms_path, multipart: true do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file %>
  <%= submit_tag "Import" %>
<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**
resources :classrooms do
  collection { post :addStudents }

**csv file i am trying to load**

```
id,email,password,password_confirmation
22,jim@gmail.com,password,password
23,jimhanks@gmail.com,password,password
```

Comment: what is the output of `row.to_hash.slice(*attr_names)`

Comment: its {} , can you please tell me why is this happening

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happening because `#to_hash` doesn't return a hash with indifferent access. You're trying to slice symbolized keys and `#to_hash` created keys as strings.

Try this:

```
def self.attr_names
  %w(email password password_confirmation)
end
```